# Jetpack Compose DrawImage compilation error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an Android application with Jetpack Compose and when I want to add a new image with DrawImage () the compilation of the kotlin language gives me an error, I am taking the code from the official Jetpack Compose example from the android developers page to add a image. I've hours looking for a answer to that issue and I dont't find anything. Could someone please help me with this error?

If I enable

```
composeOptions{
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.61-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200129"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev04"
    }
```

on my app level build.gradle file the compilation finish without error but when I run the app the image not appear and then the app crash.

This is my **MainActivity.kt** file:

```
package com.firecodes.surveyflow

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.Composable
import androidx.compose.ambient
import androidx.ui.core.ContextAmbient
import androidx.ui.core.Text
import androidx.ui.core.setContent
import androidx.ui.foundation.DrawImage
import androidx.ui.foundation.SimpleImage
import androidx.ui.graphics.imageFromResource
import androidx.ui.layout.Center
import androidx.ui.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.ui.material.Scaffold
import androidx.ui.material.TopAppBar
import androidx.ui.res.imageResource
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val context = ambient(ContextAmbient)
    Scaffold(
        topAppBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Text(text = "Hello $name")
            })
        },
        bodyContent = {
            Center {
                DrawImage(image = imageResource(id = R.drawable.surveyflow))
            }
        }
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Element is unknownThe root cause java.util.NoSuchElementException was thrown at: androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.irComposableExpr(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:1362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm$default(JvmBackendFacade.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:638)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:198)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:172)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
    at androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.irComposableExpr(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:1362)
    at androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.visitBlock(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:252)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlock(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlock(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression$DefaultImpls.transform(IrExpression.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrExpressionBase.transform(IrExpressionBase.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrTypeOperatorCallImpl.transformChildren(IrTypeOperatorCallImpl.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitTypeOperator(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:214)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitTypeOperator(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:215)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitTypeOperator(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrTypeOperatorCallImpl.accept(IrTypeOperatorCallImpl.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression$DefaultImpls.transform(IrExpression.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrExpressionBase.transform(IrExpressionBase.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.transformChildren(IrVariableImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.accept(IrVariableImpl.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrDeclaration$DefaultImpls.transform(IrDeclaration.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrDeclarationBase.transform(IrDeclarationBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.transformChildren(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.accept(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBody$DefaultImpls.transform(IrBody.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody$DefaultImpls.transform(IrBody.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.transform(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFunctionBase.transformChildren(IrFunctionBase.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFunctionImpl.accept(IrFunctionImpl.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrDeclaration$DefaultImpls.transform(IrDeclaration.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrDeclarationBase.transform(IrDeclarationBase.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
    at androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.lower(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.LowerKt.lower(Lower.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$makeIrModulePhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$makeIrModulePhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:228)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLower.lower(JvmLower.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:91)
    ... 37 more


e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

This is my app level build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.71"
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha04"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

and this is my app level build.gradle file:

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firecodes.surveyflow"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /*composeOptions{
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.61-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200129"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev04"
    }*/

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    /*implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev03'*/
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Jetpack Compose UI Dependencies
    def ui_version = "0.1.0-dev04"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-layout:$ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-material:$ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-foundation:$ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-framework:$ui_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose:compose-runtime:$ui_version"
    //kotlinPlugin "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:$ui_version"

    // Firebase Dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my project level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.71"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha04"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You have commented the `ComposeOptions` in build.gradle? it's necessary for successful code generation

Answer (score 2):

error is kinda misleading but I managed to get your code work on 0.1.0-dev07 version
here is my gradle :

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.61-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200129"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev07"
}
dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev07'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev07'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev07'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev07'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev07'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

my main image showing code:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
Scaffold(
    topAppBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(text = "Hello $name")
        })
    },
    bodyContent = {
        Center {
            Image(
                (ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                    Resources.getSystem(),
                    android.R.drawable.ic_delete,
                    null
                ) as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.asImageAsset()
            )
        }
    }
)
}
```

Answer (score -10):

I was have this problem solved with:

buildFeatures {
        compose false
 }